# Matplotlib -- libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I installed matplotlib via

```
pip install matplotlib
```

When I try to save png with it, I get

```
Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.6.21
libpng warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.2.44
libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
```

`ldconfig -p | grep libpng` gives me

```
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
libpng12.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so
```

I then build `libpng1.6.21` from source and add its `lib/` to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But `ldconfig -p | grep libpng`  still gives me the samething as before. I tried rebuilding the `ldconfig` -- still only `libpng12`.

How can I let matplotlib pick up the newly installed `libpng1.6.21`?

Why is the new `libpng1.6.21` in my `LD_LIBRARY _PATH` already, but not indexed by `ldconfig`?

Comment: What does your LD_LIBRARY_PATH look like? I think you may need to have the directory of libpng1.6.21 precede the directory of libpng1.2.44

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem before. But if matplotlib was imported first, it worked fine. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

A quick workaround would be to run your interpreter / script by specifying a custom value for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, e.g.:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/ld/path python
```

or:

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/ld/path
 python
```

For more permanent solutions, you may want to update the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.profile` or similar.